# html table php and echo

Tags: php, html

The table headings appear on my web page, however the td's do not appear on my html page.            I'm trying to echo the results of the while loop into the the table td.
Can anyone please help?

```
 <table align= "centre" width="650" align="center">

  <tr> 
    <th> Post:id </th>
    <th> Title </th>
  </tr>


  <?php 
 include("includes.php"); 
 $get_posts = "select * from posts";
 $run_posts = mysql_query($get_posts);

while ($row_posts = mysql_fetch_array('$run_posts')) {

$post_id = $row_posts['post_id'];
$post_title = $row_posts['post_title'];

?> 

  <tr>   
    <td> <?php echo $post_id; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $post_title; ?> /td>  
  </tr>

<?php } ?>  // CLOSE WHILE LOOP 
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure rows are returned from your query? You don't check in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array('$run_posts')`

is incorrect, you are passing the literal string `'$run_posts'`, not the variable. Remove the single quotes:

`mysql_fetch_array($run_posts)`

Also, mysql_ functions are depreciated, use mysqli_ or PDO intead

Answer (score 0):

You have an error at "mysql_fetch_array('$run_posts')", remove the single quotes.

It has to be:

```
mysql_fetch_array($run_posts);
```

Furthermore you shouldn't use mysql because it's deprecated. You should switch to mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

1. PHP consider anything enclosed inside single quotes as a string and would treat symbols starting with $ inside double quotes as variables. So, either use:

   > ```
   > mysql_fetch_array($run_posts);
   > or
   > mysql_fetch_array("$run_posts");
   > ```
2. Its recommended to use mysqli_* now.

Answer (score 0):

You have not close TD tag correctly.

```
<tr>   
<td> <?php echo $post_id; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $post_title; ?> </td>  
</tr>
```